# Upload from Excel vba to SQL Server - generic excel file not working

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, upload

I want to create a "generic" way of uploading data to a SQL Server database via Excel upload. In my Excel file I have two sheets - one with data (`WS_data`) and one with the database table design (`WS_Table_Design`) (e.g. rows of column names).

It is been a while since I coded VBA, but this used to work (I think?) - what am I thinking wrong here?

Errors comes when I want to "post" the values into the database through `.Fields([Column]).Value`

```
Function NullCheck(x)

On Error Resume Next
If x = "" Then
    NullCheck = Null
    Else
    NullCheck = x
End If

End Function

Sub Upload_To_DB()

Dim WS_Data, WS_Table_Design As Worksheet

Dim Curent_Row, Curren_Column, Max_Datarows, i, j As Integer
Dim Array_Table_Design()


Set WS_Data = Worksheets("Data")
Set WS_Table_Design = Worksheets("DB_Table_Design")

'List Columns from Table design in array

ReDim Array_Table_Design(0 To 0)
Current_Row = 1
i = 0
    Do While WS_Table_Design.Cells(Current_Row, 1).Value <> ""

        If WS_Table_Design.Cells(Current_Row, 1).Value > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve Array_Table_Design(0 To i)
            Array_Table_Design(i) = WS_Table_Design.Cells(Current_Row, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Current_Row = Current_Row + 1
    Loop

'End List Columns

'Find number of rows to upload
Current_Row = 2 'Row where data starts
Max_Datarows = 0
Do While WS_Data.Cells(Current_Row, 1).Value <> ""
    Max_Datarows = Max_Datarows + 1

Current_Row = Current_Row + 1
Loop
'End find number of rows to upload

'Upload data according to Table design and Data sheet

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstring As String

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Datawarehouse;Data Source=server3"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "select * from FactGL", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Current_Row = 2
Current_Column = 1
i = 0
j = 0
For j = 0 To 5 'Max_Datarows

    rs.AddNew
    For i = 0 To UBound(Array_Table_Design)

'Error comes here - why can't I add data to the database Table column defined in "Array_Table_Design?
            rs.Fields("Array_Table_Design(i)").Value = NullCheck(WS_Data.Cells(Current_Row, i + 1).Value)
            i = i + 1
        Next i
        rs.Update
        Current_Row = Current_Row + 1
    Next j

    End Sub
```

Comment: "Errors come" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: Sorry - of course. I get run time error 3265

Comment: The *text* of the error message is as important as the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
rs.Fields("Array_Table_Design(i)").Value
```

should be

```
rs.Fields(Array_Table_Design(i)).Value
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this - and get "run time error 3265" back. I take this as if the connection does not recongize the table column/field I want to add data to?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up!
The error 3265 is now not that relevant anymore.
I found out that the .Fields() function does not need [] for column names, e.g. I had added column names, that were invalid. I simply removed the [] from my "table design" list.
Secondly, I discovered that I have excel date format (e.g. numbers) that I am trying to upload to a SQL datetime format. Which will not work. E.g. I will have to make a function checking whether it is an excel date that should be converted to SQL datetime (not sure yet - maybe I will simply not make a generic function for this)...